# How to get values of b and n in one data frame which is in to a nested for loop?

Tags: r

```
df1 <- data.frame (tm=c(1,3,5,7,9),dm=c(2,8,5,7,9),cm=c(2,8,6,8,10),km=c(1,10,5,7,10))

for (i in 1:length (df1) ){ 
  for (j in 2:length (df1)) {
    b <- as.numeric ((cor (df1[i],df1[j])));
    fg <- names (df1[i]);
    kg <- names (df1[j]);
    n <- paste(fg,"&",kg, sep = "");
    print (n)
    print (b)

    }
}

Output of Print (n)) is :
[1] "tm&dm"
[1] "tm&cm"
[1] "tm&km"
[1] "dm&dm"
[1] "dm&cm"
[1] "dm&km"
[1] "cm&dm"
[1] "cm&cm"
[1] "cm&km"
[1] "km&dm"
[1] "km&cm"
[1] "km&km"

Output of Print (b)) is :
[1] 0.7407437
[1] 0.8340577
[1] 0.6271815
[1] 1
[1] 0.9861405
[1] 0.9863407
[1] 0.9861405
[1] 1
[1] 0.9503084
[1] 0.9863407
[1] 0.9503084
[1] 1

  Newdata <- [ n   b ]
```

Now I want a data frame which contains n and b. Please help me.

Comment: @RaibulIslam Are you looking for solutions in R or java/php etc?

Comment: You forgot to tag Python and JavaScript.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and remove tags other than [tag:r] since they are completely irrelevant in the given context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an R solution:

Create empty lists and fill it in the *for loop*

```
n_list <- c()
b_list <- c()

for (i in 1:length (df1) ){ 
  for (j in 2:length (df1)) {
    b <- as.numeric ((cor (df1[i],df1[j])));
    fg <- names (df1[i]);
    kg <- names (df1[j]);
    n <- paste(fg,"&",kg, sep = "");
    n_list = c(n_list,n)
    b_list = c(b_list,b)

    }
}

data.frame(n=n_list, b=b_list)
```